# Why is Meteor Mongo collection inaccessible on the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, meteor-collections

I have a piece of code show below that creates a Mongo collection as show below. However whenever I try to access the collection from inside of the Meteor.isClient scope I get an error. Please can anyone spot my mistake.

```
ImagesCollection  = new Mongo.Collection("Images");
Images  = new Mongo.Collection("Images");

if(Meteor.isClient){
  Template.body.helpers({ images :
        function() {
          console.log("Template Loade");
          return Images.find({},{sort: -1 });
        }
  }) ;

  Template.Images.events({
      'click .js-image' : function(event){
        $(event.target).css("Width", "50px");
      } ,
      'click .js-del-image' : function(event){
          var image_id  = this._id ;
          $("#"+image_id).hide({slow });
          Images.remove({"_id" : image_id});
      },

      'click .js-rate-image' : function(event){
          var  rating =  $(event.currentTarget).data("userrating");
          var image_id =  this.id ;

          Images.find({"_id": image_id});
      }


  });

}
```

The content of my Startup.js is as below as well

```
if(Meteor.isServer){

    Meteor.startup(function(){

      for(var i  = 0 ; i<=23 ;  i++)
      {
          Images.insert({
             'img_src' :  'img_'+i+'.jpg' ,
             'img_alt'  :  'Image number' +  i
           });
            console.log(Images.find().count);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Are you using the autopublish package? If not, you need to publish/subscribe to your collection ([guide](http://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html)).

Comment: The autoplublish and insecure package are added to my webapp.

Comment: - What is the error message ?

Comment: Also, .find() return a cursor, not a Array. Is that what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

```
consle.log("Template Loade");
```

Since you don't specify your error, the line above will raise an error.

Comment: I have corrected the typo in my code. This was not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the code that you have provided, there are two problems that I can see.

First, in your `images` template helper, your second parameter for the `Images.find()` function call is incorrect. You are missing a document field specification for the sort operation. This second parameter needs to be in the format `{sort: {'document_field': -1}}`. Although you have not provided the error text that you are seeing, I suspect the error has something to do with Mongo not being able to process the query, and this would be the reason for that.

Second, although this is less severe and should not be causing the problems with your inability to access the `Images` collection on the client, in your `console.log()` statement in your server `Meteor.startup()` code you are accessing `count` as if it is a property on the cursor returned from the `Images.find()` function call. In actuality, it is a function and should be called like so: `Images.find().count()`.

Also, as an aside, I would suggest that you give different names to your two collections that you have defined. Giving them both the same name may cause issues for you if you are trying to manipulate data through the Mongo shell.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is an issue, but why are you initializing twice the "images" collection ?

`ImagesCollection  = new Mongo.Collection("Images");`

`Images  = new Mongo.Collection("Images");`

And ImagesCollection is not used anywhere in you're code.
Try to remove one of this lines.